# How to keep personalization when moving class derived from WebPartManager to new assembly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

We have a web site project that was started many years ago. The landing page uses personalizable web parts, and the web part manager is an extension of the .NET WebPartManager class, residing in App_Code. The curious thing is that if we move this class into another assembly in the same solution, the personalization is cleared and we can save new personalization. But when we move the class back, it loads the original personalization again. The PathId, UserId, and ApplicationId all appear to stay the same in the asp_PersonalizationPerUser table (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478955.aspx for details.)

UPDATE: The reason I ask is because we need to convert our project to a Web Application project, and we do not want to cause any disruption among some the 500 users that use the application daily. I have put a shelveset together for the conversion and everything seems to be worked out except for this problem.

UPDATE 2: It occurred to me that I need to re-word my question.

**How can I keep personalization when moving our class that derives from WebPartManager to a new assembly?**

Comment: Looking at the PersonalizationState blob in the database, it's tracking the types of things, including the WebPartManager derivative (particular assembly and all) and the reference to "System.Web.UI.UserControl" (which is showing as framework version 4.0 now in the WebApp project.) So basically, I am going to have to either have some intermediary stuff going on to cause it to ignore the type of the WebPartManager, or I am going to have to write a utility script to convert all of the database records to refer to the derivative type. Any suggestions and help welcome, and bounty-eligible.

Comment: After scouring the source with JustCompile, I *think* it's something that is obscured within an internal class (`BlobPersonalizationState`), so I would either have to copy and a lot of source code to ignore the type difference, or write a DB conversion script to go in and change the `Type` string. I'll keep analyzing... don't make me reward myself with my own bounty here :)

Comment: In particular, 
        `private void ApplyPersonalization(Control control, string personalizationID, bool isWebPartManager, PersonalizationScope extractScope, GenericWebPart genericWebPart)` is where it marks the WebPartManager control as dirty if the type is not matching.

Comment: Running through debugger (switching the class back and forth between projects to cause the unwanted behavior purposely), I have found that `WebPartManager.LoadCustomPersonalizationState` is not called the first time I load the page after switch the class around. Now to find out why that is.

Comment: JustDecompile shows that the method is called by `WebPartManager.IPersonalizable.Load`, and that is called by `WebPartManager.ImportFromReader` (which uses an XML reader, so that is irrelevant), as well as `WebPartPersonalization.ApplyPersonalizationState` (which traces up to `WebPartManager.AddWebPart` as part of a postback event, so that is irrelevant) and `BlobPersonalizationState.ApplyPersonalization`, which is where I was at earlier. Now it's time to step into the source in debugger to watch what happens!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the implementation is very complicated and internal to the .NET framework, creating a custom source code to manage this is unfeasible. Instead, running a database script during maintenance will be the best option. Example:

```
// Read the 'PageSettings' column from the ASP personalization tables
// into a byte array variable called 'rawData' first. Then continue:

var mems = new System.IO.MemoryStream(rawData);
var formatter = new System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter();
var oldState = formatter.Deserialize(mems) as object[];

var index = oldState.ToList()
                    .FindIndex(o =>
                        o as Type != null &&
                        ((Type)o).Name.Contains("WebPartManager"));

// In our case, the derivative class name is "MyWebPartManager", you
// may need to change that to meet your requirements

oldState[index] = typeof(WebPartManager);

mems = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
formatter.Serialize(mems, oldState);
var newState = mems.ToArray();

// Write 'newState' back into the database.
```

Answer (score 0):

> In addition to scoping personalization state by user name and path,
>   SqlPersonalizationProvider supports scoping by application name.
>   Websites that register personalization providers with identical
>   applicationName attributes share Web Parts personalization data,
>   whereas websites that register personalization providers with unique
>   applicationNames do not. Due to the page-specific and control-specific
>   nature of personalization data, however, it usually doesn't make sense
>   to use the same applicationName for Web Parts personalization data
>   across different websites.

Does your new Web Application project have a different applicationName than the old one?

Comment: No. The application name and ID (and anything in web.config related to personalization) remain the same.